# Non deterministic trivial C program

Tags: c

The following C program has a different output if I write something inside my main function and I really don't understand why..

If we comment the myVariable declaration, everything is fine and we obtain the expecting result (applying 3 times SHA256 to 0x12345678). But, if I write anything in the main function, then the output changes and doesn't take the expected value.

How is it possible that declaring a new variable affects this ?

**The code (precompute.c) :**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/sha.h>

unsigned char* sha256_3(int* input) {
    char *s = (char*)input;
    unsigned char *d = SHA256(s, strlen(s), 0);
    d = SHA256(d, strlen(d), 0);
    d = SHA256(d, strlen(d), 0);

    return d;
}

void print_hash(unsigned char* d) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        printf("%02x", d[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int A = 0x12345678;
    unsigned char *B = sha256_3(&A);
    print_hash(B);

    // int myVariable = 3; // Uncomment this line and recompile to see the difference

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**The Makefile :**

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c
LDFLAGS=-lssl -lcrypto
SOURCES=precompute.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.c .o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

The expected output (declaration of myVariable commented):

> 8f3d8f8c5eff23dc137762220cf24f140b7a1b804cc2044261742fd73286c169

An unexpected output (declaration of myVariable uncommented):

> 663e9571f713f83b19c913938e2947c8fc0a7072d1fc442385857c456c43295b

Thank you very much!

Comment: you never allocated any space. you're just writing to random memory (UB)

Comment: also pretty much none of those lines of C make any sense. reading from  and writing to the same memory, repeatedly writing to pointers as if they were primitives. this doesn't look redeemable, just start over.

Comment: The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character, so `strlen(s)` is UB , as `s` is just pointing to some memory  chunk

Answer (score 0):

By analysing this snippet:

```
char *s = (char*)input;
unsigned char *d = SHA256(s, strlen(s), 0);
```

Few mistakes can be seen. `input` is originally a pointer to an int (defined by the line with `int A`). An int has usually 4 bytes. When you cast a pointer to it to char*, that's fine, you pointer points to an allocated memory of 4 bytes. But, all functions in string.h, including strlen(), rely on the presence of a NUL ('\0') character at the end of the string. Basically, strlen() counts how many characters are there until NUL. As you don't have a NUL character after those 4 bytes from the int, the result is based on what can be found in memory (somewhere may be a 0 in memory, which is the value of the NUL character, and strlen stops).

Now, to fix it, you have 2 possible solutions: either create a string from the beginning with the values you need, or, in sha256_3 function, create a string of 5 bytes, copy the 4 ones from the int provided as parameter and assign NUL to the last one.